How to customize font family of the text in custom notification (NotificationCompat.dectoratedCustomViewStyle()) in android? full width big content?
How to use custom fonts for text in notifications in android, i have tried a way of creating folder "font" and the add font.ttf file to "font/file_name.ttf" but its not working. I want to change by default text font in notification.enter image description here
MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper"
    private lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSessionCompat

     override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)

        mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "MediaSession")

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "showNotificationFromNative" -> {
                    val title = call.argument<String>("title") ?: "Empty"
                    val message = call.argument<String>("message") ?: "Empty"
                    val greetings = showSimpleNotification(title, message)
                    result.success(greetings)
                }
                "showCustomNotificationFromNative" -> {
                    val args = call.arguments as? Map<String, Any>
                    if (args != null) {
                        val greetings = showCustomNotification(args)
                        result.success(greetings)
                    } else {
                        result.error("INVALID_ARGUMENTS", "Arguments must be a Map<String, Any>", null)
                    }
                }
                "showMediaNotification" -> {
                    val title = call.argument<String>("title") ?: ""
                    val artist = call.argument<String>("artist") ?: ""
                    val album = call.argument<String>("album") ?: ""
                    val duration = call.argument<Int>("duration") ?: 0
                    val position = call.argument<Int>("position") ?: 0
                    showMediaNotification(title, artist, album, duration, position)
                    result.success(null)
                }
                else -> {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    
    

    private fun showCustomNotification(args: Map<String, Any>): String {
    val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val channelId = "i.apps.custom.notification"
    val description = "Custom Charging Notification"
    val isFirstUpdate = args["is_first_update"] as Boolean
    val isStillCharging = args["isStillCharging"] as Boolean

    // Create and configure the notification channel
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && isFirstUpdate) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(false)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }

    // Build the notification
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_charging_small)
        .setOngoing(isStillCharging)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setContentTitle("${args["device_name"]}")
        .setContentText("${args["current_percentage"]}% / ${args["estimate_percentage"]}% by ${args["estimate_time"]}")

    // Add a progress bar
    val maxProgress = args["estimate_percentage"].toString().toInt()
    val currentProgress = args["current_percentage"].toString().toInt()
    

    // Create a custom layout
    val customLayout = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_expanded)
    customLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.charging_title, "${args["device_name"]}")
    customLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.charging_estimate, "${args["estimate_percentage"]}% by ${args["estimate_time"]}")
    customLayout.setProgressBar(R.id.charging_progress, maxProgress, currentProgress, false)
    customLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.charging_percentage, "${args["current_percentage"]}%")

    // Set the custom layout
    builder.setCustomBigContentView(customLayout)
    builder.setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
    // builder.setStyle(MediaStyle())



    // Show the notification


    notificationManager.notify(12345, builder.build())
    return "Success"
}





file for layout and UI -> "res/layout/notification_expanded.xml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/charging_background_image_dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_charging"
                    android:tint="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/charging_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:text="Charging"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/conigen"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/charging_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:text="Raptrix"
                    
                    android:textColor="#08999F"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/charging_estimate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="80% by 9:30 AM"
                
                android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>




I want the solution to customize the font family in the text inside notification.
